# C# Bitwise Operands Vs PHP

Tags: c#, php, xor, operand

I'm trying to convert some C# code into PHP.

The C# code is as follows:

```
strRequest="\auth\\pid\3045\ch\ehCkPNGS\resp\1529559b837decb2e0ed2f576806f10aeda4d9cdf781acd3e53ad1c3b11a20684f131229\ip\16777343\skey\3759\reqproof\1";
byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strRequest);
Encode(sendBuffer, strRequest.Length);

private static void Encode(byte[] buff, int size){
        byte[] tmp = new byte[8];
        tmp[0] = 103;
        tmp[1] = 97;
        tmp[2] = 109;
        tmp[3] = 101;
        tmp[4] = 115;
        tmp[5] = 112;
        tmp[6] = 121;
        tmp[7] = 0;

        if (size != 0){
            int i = size;
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            do{
                if (tmp[j] == 0)
                    j = 0;

                buff[k++] ^= tmp[j++];
                --i;
            } while (i != 0);
        }
}
```

Which should output a byte array of:
`'59','0','24','17','27','44','37','23','8','9','57','64','64','77','82','61','14','13','47','21','17','36','10','61','43','52','35','37','21','4','30','21','47','65','76','85','88','88','80','74','18','65','84','86','9','0','16','18','75','2','81','8','1','65','22','76','80','87','85','85','69','22','72','87','0','8','1','18','68','29','94','2','9','3','68','72','72','6','2','9','86','22','69','74','6','5','92','6','64','18','72','86','0','95','85','69','72','77','1','80','94','84','65','66','64','59','8','29','57','66','70','78','80','86','94','81','64','44','10','12','4','20','57','64','71','76','94','61','31','0','2','0','11','8','14','11','57','66',`

My equivalent PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php

$strReq="\\auth\\\\pid\\3045\\ch\\atGzgVH5\\resp\\1529559b837decb2e0ed2f576806f10ac7d8b28205dcbd64c59666a11d43b814024837cb\\ip\\16777343\\skey\\1292\\reqproof\\1";

$strReqLen = strlen($strReq);

$strHex = unpack("C*",$strReq);

$test = Encode($strHex,$strReqLen);

print_r ($test);

function Encode($buff, $size){

$tmp = array(103,97,109,101,115,112,121,0);

$tester = array();
if ($size != 0){
$i = $size;
$j = 0;
$k = 0;

do {
    if($tmp[$j] == 0){
        $j = 0;
    }       
    $buff[$k++] ^= $tmp[$j++];
    --$i;
} while ($i != 0);
}
return $buff;
}

?>
```

But does not output anything like what the C# code does.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Could it be the PHP array contains type int, the c# uses bytes?

Comment: That was my first thought but I can't find a byte array for PHP.

Comment: What will happen if you change the c# code to array of int? (just for results compare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# uses zero-based arrays but PHP's unpack(..) uses a 1-based array.

You could either change

```
$strHex = unpack("C*",$strReq);
```

to

```
$strHex = array_merge(unpack("C*",$strReq));
```

to make your PHP array zero-based, or simply set `$k` to an initial value of 1.

After testing either solution the PHP results are the same as the C# output.

Comment: Turns out Alex is spot on!
I changed my $K variable to 1 and now it gives the exact expected output!
Thanks Alex!